# how to adjust relevancy in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I am using elastic search using snowball analyzer to search at one field (called caption).
When I searched for 'dress korea', it also returns results with dress only and korea only. Is it possible to limit the search so it has to contain both search term/query? If so how do I do so? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the query you are using.

For example, with [Simple Query String query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-simple-query-string-query), you can add a `AND` flag.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html you would need to include an operator of 'AND'.